# iOS - Cannot get an @IBDesignable .xib file to show up on storyboard or simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, xib

I have set the file owner to be UserBannerView.
The UIView in the storyboard that uses this .xib file is also set to be UserBannerView. 
I am not getting any errors, yet it won't show up in either the simulator or the storyboard.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class UserBannerView: UIView {

var view: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var userCreditsLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var userRenewDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: circlePP!
@IBOutlet weak var userMembershipBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

var nibName:String = "UserBannerView"

public override init(frame:CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    print("UserBannerView init from frame")
    setup()
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    print("UserBannerView init from decode")
    setup()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    print("UserBannerView awakeFromNib")

   // setup()
}

func setup() {
        print("UserBannerView:setup")
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "UserBannerView", bundle: bundle)
        self.view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        self.view.frame = bounds
        self.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a view in my storyboard with the Class as UserBannerView, which invokes the init?(coder aDecoder:NScoder). Then I have a UserBannerView.xib file

Comment: And what is the class set for your `UserBannerView` in the .xib file?

Comment: Try following this guide. I've done this several times, tried checking your code but don't see anything wrong. So maybe some of the assignments in the interface builder are not set properly. Just in case try this one step by step:
http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

Comment: @Pochi That link worked for me. Thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 3):

Try implementing your `awakeFromNib` method and add `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` method

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setup()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setup()
}
```

Also make sure that your class is setted as fileOwner in your xib file

Hope this helps