# xcode Interface Builder not updating IBDesignable class

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ibdesignable

In my project, I have several custom class files based on UITextField and UIButton.

As an example, the UITextField class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RoundedTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        layer.cornerRadius = 25
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        clipsToBounds = true
        textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        // Placeholder colour
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)])
    }

    // Placeholder text indent
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 5)
    }

    // Editing text indent
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 5)
    }
}
```

Here is the correct version that the simulator shows me:
[SimScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29tL1.png)

Here is what IB shows me:
[IBScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZJTr.png)

As you can see from my IB screenshot, the only element that updates is the indentation of the placeholder text. The rest of the customisation from the class is not updating.

Any thoughts?

P.s. when I select an element, in the identity inspector, the 'Designables' field is "Up to date".

I have tried cleaning, building and restarting Xcode.

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408409/weird-issue-while-using-ibdesignable-uilabel-class/45408532#45408532 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533610/ios-cannot-get-an-ibdesignable-xib-file-to-show-up-on-storyboard-or-simulato/44547101#44547101

Comment: Thanks Reinier, I used your second link and another source to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with help from Reinier's 2nd link and a course I previously took on Udemy.

I implemented my customisation in a `setupView()` function. I called this in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` and also `awakeFromNib()`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RoundedTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setupView()
    }

    // Placeholder text indent
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 5)
    }

    // Editing text indent
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 5)
    }

    func setupView() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 25
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        clipsToBounds = true
        textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        // Placeholder colour
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//It will update both Simulator and InterfaceBuilder

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class ViewExtended: UIView {
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }
    func setupView() {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.7 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 4.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3) {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```